# Relatively new to working out, but have made my own routine I've been trying for a bit and wanna know what I could or should change about it

Tags: workout-routines, workout

So I started working out around September of last year, and along the way I sort of formed my own routine. It's a take on PPL, and so far it's not only been making alright results but it's very enjoyable and convenient for me. I just want to know if I should change anything to make it more optimal for my goals, which are mass gain and strength gain. For some partial reference of my progress so far (I got bad memory so this is all I got haha), when I began my max for bench was 135 and now I use 165 for my working sets, and before I couldn't deadlift 225 and now I can do 225 for 3 sets of 8. I feel stronger, but I also feel I could be progressing much faster, and I just wanna bump out any kinks in my program, or switch to something else if I should. Anything helps, thanks.

So rather than following a *"Monday - Push, Tuesday - Pull"* type regimen, it's on a 4 day cycle instead with variation between each cycle.
It looks like:

**-Push A**

**-Legs (no B variation, should probably make one)**

**-Pull A**

**-Rest**

**-(repeat but with B exercises)**

I don't work out at specific times, but usually head to the gym around 6 to 9 in the evening.

Here's the workouts I do. Everything is taken to failure.

**Push A**: Warm up with 2 or 3 minute runs on the treadmill, stretch, light weight seated rows to ready traps for stability, 3x8 Converging Bench Machine, 3x12 Tricep Straight-Bar Pushdowns, 3x8 Chest Fly Machine w/ a drop set immediately after the final set, 4x10 Bodyweight Dips with Tricep Focus, 3x10 Converging Decline Bench Machine with the final set close grip, then a drop set after, 3x10 Lateral Raises (first two sets are along scapular plane, last set is straight out), 3x10 Supinated Front Raises. *Usually about an hour in the gym.*

**Push B**: Same Warmup as A, 3x7 Bench Press, 3x10 Skull Crushers, 3x8 Chest Fly Machine w/ drop set, 3x10 Overhead Press, 3x25 Pushups, 3x10 Lateral Raises (same way as before), 2x14 Supinated Front Raises. *Usually an hour.*

**Legs**: 2x10 Sissy Squats for warmup, stretch, 3x8 Pendulum Squats w/ drop set, 3x10 Seated Hamstring Curls, 4x15 Leg Press Calf Raises, 3x12 Leg Extensions w/ drop set, 3x8 Romanian Deadlifts. *Usually 40 minutes*

**Pull A**: 1 mile jog, stretch, 3x10 Dumbell Curls, 3x8 Single Arm Cable Lat Pulldowns, 3x7 Chest Supported Rows, 3x8 Close Grip Seated Cable Rows, 3x15 Shrugs, 3x8 Deadlifts, 3x8 EZ Bar Pronated Grip Curls. *Usually an hour.*

**Pull B**: 1 mile jog, stretch, 3x10 Barbell Curls, 3x8 Lat Pulldowns, 3x8 Seated Row Machine, 3x8 Barbell Rows, 3x8 Deadlifts, 3x10 Hammer Curls, 3x10 Rear Delt Flies. *Usually an hour*

Overall, it's fun and convenient, though I'm not 100% strict with it. Sometimes I'll either swap a workout for another that works the same things or add in some more exercises if I feel like it, but these essentially serve as guidelines I follow for the most part. The only thing I really change with the routine is sometimes I skip the rest day cause I wanna go to the gym, or on the rest day I go anyways and do a light full-body calisthenics workout.

If there's anything I should change, add, remove, or if it just looks good, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: “Mass gain” is easy enough to measure, but when you say “strength gain”, I think you need to be more specific about what exactly you’re measuring. What is your metric for “strength gain”? Deadlift 1RM? Bicep curl 1RM? Standing vertical jump?

Comment: Well I feel being able to put high numbers up, so yeah like deadlift 1rm, bench 1rm, etc.

Comment: What's your progression model? How are you progressing the exercises? Increase in weight? Increase in volume? Decrease in rest?